# Integrate codeigniter RESTApi with Payu payment gateway

Tags: php, codeigniter, payu

Working with codeigniter shopping cart, we purchased payment gateway from PayU india. I can integrate this gateway using below code in normal php.

```
pay_page( array ('key' => 'gtKFFx', 'txnid' => uniqid( 'animesh_' ), 'amount' => rand( 0, 100 ),
            'firstname' => 'Test', 'email' => 'test@payu.in', 'phone' => '98765433210',
            'productinfo' => 'Product Info', 'surl' => 'payment_success', 'furl' => 'payment_failure'), 
            'eCwWELxi' );
```

In my php controller included payu helper and written the above code but errors comes like(I need to redirect my application to payu screen, having problem in redirect)

```
  XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://test.payu.in/_payment_options?mihpayid=3690c101118c75fb7d0ca8e75cf19e5e81c4d2b99fbb9da371f70d2f01273bdf. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:90' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Did find the answer? I''m facing the same problem with my application.